# Let X be a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X be a discrete random variable. If $E[X]=-3$, then

$E[(3+5X)^2]=$

I understand that to find the expected value the formula would be $E[aX+b] = aE[X]+b$ 
so it would be 3+5(-3). My problem is that I do not know what to do with the square. Where would I put it in the formula. I tried squaring my answer, but it was wrong. What is the formula in an expected value that is squared?

Comment: It seems that there is information missing; it is impossible to calculate $\mathbb{E}[(3+5X)^2]$ given only $\mathbb{E}X$. Is anything about $\mathbb{E}X^2$ known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not enough information to answer the question.  For example, I could construct $$\Pr[X = -5] = \Pr[X = -1] = 1/2,$$ hence $\mathrm{E}[X]  = (-5)\Pr[X = -5] + (-1)\Pr[X = -1] = (-5-1)/2 = -3$.  Now let $$\Pr[Y = -4] = \Pr[Y = -2] = 1/2,$$ and again $\mathrm{E}[Y] = -3$.  But $$\mathrm{E}[(3+5X)^2] = (3+5(-5))^2 \cdot \tfrac{1}{2} + (3+5(-1))^2 \cdot \tfrac{1}{2} = \tfrac{22^2 + 2^2}{2} = 244,$$ whereas $$\mathrm{E}[(3+5Y)^2] = (3+5(-4))^2 \cdot \tfrac{1}{2} + (3+5(-2))^2 \cdot \tfrac{1}{2} = \tfrac{17^2 + 7^2}{2} = 169,$$ which demonstrates that there is no unique answer.